# Is there any disadvantage of writing a long constructor?

Tags: oop

Does it affect the time in loading the application?
or any other issues in doing so?

Comment: What do you mean by a "long" constructor? In name? In parameter list? In length of code/number of lines regardless of algorithmic complexity?

Comment: @sharptooth - I always give my variables really long names so there are less pixels to light on the screen.

Comment: @CurtainDog: I solved the problem another way: I changed the editor settings to "green letters, black background" - now the area to light is drastically smaller and I don't need to enforce longer variable names for the sake of energy efficiency.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The question is vague on what "long" means. Here are some possible interpretations:

#### Interpretation #1: The constructor has many parameters

Constructors with many parameters can lead to poor readability, and better alternatives exist.

Here's a quote from *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 2: Consider a builder pattern when faced with many constructor parameters*:

> Traditionally, programmers have used the *telescoping constructor* pattern, in which you provide a constructor with only the required parameters, another with a single optional parameters, a third with two optional parameters, and so on...

The telescoping constructor pattern is essentially something like this:

```
public class Telescope {
    final String name;
    final int levels;
    final boolean isAdjustable;

    public Telescope(String name) {
        this(name, 5);
    }
    public Telescope(String name, int levels) {
        this(name, levels, false);
    }
    public Telescope(String name, int levels, boolean isAdjustable) {       
        this.name = name;
        this.levels = levels;
        this.isAdjustable = isAdjustable;
    }
}
```

And now you can do any of the following:

```
new Telescope("X/1999");
new Telescope("X/1999", 13);
new Telescope("X/1999", 13, true);
```

You can't, however, currently set only the `name` and `isAdjustable`, and leaving `levels` at default. You can provide more constructor overloads, but obviously the number would explode as the number of parameters grow, and you may even have multiple `boolean` and `int` arguments, which would really make a mess out of things.

As you can see, this isn't a pleasant pattern to write, and even less pleasant to use (What does "true" mean here? What's 13?).

Bloch recommends using a builder pattern, which would allow you to write something like this instead:

```
Telescope telly = new Telescope.Builder("X/1999").setAdjustable(true).build();
```

Note that now the parameters are named, and you can set them in any order you want, and you can skip the ones that you want to keep at default values. This is certainly much better than telescoping constructors, especially when there's a huge number of parameters that belong to many of the same types.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)
- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 2: Consider a builder pattern when faced with many constructor parameters* ([excerpt online](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/EffectiveJava.aspx))

#### Related questions

- [When would you use the Builder Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern)
- [Is this a well known design pattern? What is its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637268/is-this-a-well-known-design-pattern-what-is-its-name/)

---

#### Interpretation #2: The constructor does a lot of work that costs time

If the work must be done at construction time, then doing it in the constructor or in a helper method doesn't really make too much of a difference. When a constructor delegates work to a helper method, however, make sure that it's not overridable, because that could lead to a lot of problems.

Here's some quote from *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 17: Design and document for inheritance, or else prohibit it*:

> There are a few more restrictions that a class must obey to allow inheritance. **Constructors must not invoke overridable methods**, directly or indirectly. If you violate this rule, program failure will result. The superclass constructor runs before the subclass constructor, so the overriding method in the subclass will be invoked before the subclass constructor has run. If the overriding method depends on any initialization performed by the subclass constructor, the method will not behave as expected.

Here's an example to illustrate:

```
public class ConstructorCallsOverride {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        abstract class Base {
            Base() { overrideMe(); }
            abstract void overrideMe(); 
        }
        class Child extends Base {
            final int x;
            Child(int x) { this.x = x; }
            @Override void overrideMe() {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
        new Child(42); // prints "0"
    }
}
```

Here, when `Base` constructor calls `overrideMe`, `Child` has not finished initializing the `final int x`, and the method gets the wrong value. This will almost certainly lead to bugs and errors.

---

#### Interpretation #3: The constructor does a lot of work that can be deferred

The construction of an object can be made faster when some work is deferred to when it's actually needed; this is called *lazy initialization*. As an example, when a `String` is constructed, it does not actually compute its hash code. It only does it when the hash code is first required, and then it will cache it (since strings are immutable, this value will not change).

However, consider *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 71: Use lazy initialization judiciously*. Lazy initialization can lead to subtle bugs, and don't always yield improved performance that justifies the added complexity. Do not prematurely optimize.

Comment: Yes, Effective Java is our Principia Mathematica. Also, I am lamenting the fact that I can only upvote your answer once.

Comment: Interpretation #1: The constructor has many parameters - I think it's worth mentioning that having many constructor parameters could mean the class has two many dependencies and might be trying to do too much

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are a little special in that an unhandled exception in a constructor may have weird side effects. Without seeing your code I would assume that a long constructor increases the risk of exceptions. I would make the constructor as simple as needed and utilize other methods to do the rest in order to provide better error handling.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest disadvantage is probably the same as writing any other long function -- that it can get complex and difficult to understand.

The rest is going to vary. First of all, length and execution time don't necessarily correlate -- you could have a single line (e.g., function call) that took several seconds to complete (e.g., connect to a server) or lots of code that executed entirely within the CPU and finished quickly.

Startup time would (obviously) only be affected by constructors that were/are invoked during startup. I haven't had an issue with this in any code I've written (at all recently anyway), but I've seen code that did. On some types of embedded systems (for one example) you really want to avoid creating and destroying objects during normal use, so you create almost everything statically during bootup. Once it's running, you can devote all the processor time to getting the real work done.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is yet another function. You need very long functions called many times to make the program work slow. So if it's only called once it usually won't matter how much code is inside.

Answer (score 0):

It affects the time it takes to construct that object, naturally, but no more than having an empty constructor and calling methods to do that work instead. It has no effect on the application load time

Answer (score 0):

In case of copy constructor if we use donot use reference in that case
it will create an object and call the copy constructor and passing the
value to the copy constructor and each time a new object is created and
each time it will call the copy constructor it goes to infinite and
fill the memory then it display the error message .

if we pass the reference it will not create the new object for storing
the value. and no recursion will take place

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid doing anything in your constructor that isn't absolutely necessary. Initialize your variables in there, and try not to do much else. Additional functionality should reside in separate functions that you call only if you need to.